# perform Deming regression without intercept

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, least-squares, coefficients

I would like to perform Deming regression (or any equivalent of a regression method with uncertainties in both X and Y variables, such as York regression).

In my application, I have a very good scientific justification to deliberately **set the intercept as zero**. However, I can't find way of setting it to zero, either in R package `deming`, it gives an error when I use `-1` in the formula:

```
df=data.frame(x=rnorm(10), y=rnorm(10), sx=runif(10), sy=runif(10))
library(deming)
deming(y~x-1, df, xstd=sy, ystd=sy)
Error in lm.wfit(x, y, wt/ystd^2) : 'x' must be a matrix
```

In other packages (like `mcr::mcreg` or `IsoplotR::york` or `MethComp::Deming`), the input are two vectors x and y, so there is no way I can input a model matrix or modify the formula.

Do you have any idea on how to achieve that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the function when you remove the intercept. I'm going to report it.

It is easy to fix, you just have to change 2 lines in the original function. 
The print does not work correctly, but it is possible to interpret the output.

```
deming.aux <- 
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, cv = FALSE, 
          xstd, ystd, stdpat, conf = 0.95, jackknife = TRUE, dfbeta = FALSE, 
          x = FALSE, y = FALSE, model = TRUE) 
{

  deming.fit1 <- getAnywhere(deming.fit1)[[2]][[1]]
  deming.fit2 <- getAnywhere(deming.fit2)[[2]][[1]]

  Call <- match.call()
  indx <- match(c("formula", "data", "weights", "subset", "na.action", "xstd", "ystd"), names(Call), nomatch = 0)
  if (indx[1] == 0) 
    stop("A formula argument is required")
  temp <- Call[c(1, indx)]
  temp[[1]] <- as.name("model.frame")
  mf <- eval(temp, parent.frame())
  Terms <- terms(mf)
  n <- nrow(mf)
  if (n < 3) 
    stop("less than 3 non-missing observations in the data set")
  xstd <- model.extract(mf, "xstd")
  ystd <- model.extract(mf, "ystd")
  Y <- as.matrix(model.response(mf, type = "numeric"))
  if (is.null(Y)) 
    stop("a response variable is required")
  wt <- model.weights(mf)
  if (length(wt) == 0) 
    wt <- rep(1, n)
  usepattern <- FALSE
  if (is.null(xstd)) {
    if (!is.null(ystd)) 
      stop("both of xstd and ystd must be given, or neither")
    if (missing(stdpat)) {
      if (cv) 
        stdpat <- c(0, 1, 0, 1)
      else stdpat <- c(1, 0, 1, 0)
    }
    else {
      if (any(stdpat < 0) || all(stdpat[1:2] == 0) || all(stdpat[3:4] == 
                                                          0)) 
        stop("invalid stdpat argument")
    }
    if (stdpat[2] > 0 || stdpat[4] > 0) 
      usepattern <- TRUE
    else {
      xstd <- rep(stdpat[1], n)
      ystd <- rep(stdpat[3], n)
    }
  }
  else {
    if (is.null(ystd)) 
      stop("both of xstd and ystd must be given, or neither")
    if (!is.numeric(xstd)) 
      stop("xstd must be numeric")
    if (!is.numeric(ystd)) 
      stop("ystd must be numeric")
    if (any(xstd <= 0)) 
      stop("xstd must be positive")
    if (any(ystd <= 0)) 
      stop("ystd must be positive")
  }
  if (conf < 0 || conf >= 1) 
    stop("invalid confidence level")
  if (!is.logical(dfbeta)) 
    stop("dfbeta must be TRUE or FALSE")
  if (dfbeta & !jackknife) 
    stop("the dfbeta option only applies if jackknife=TRUE")
  X <- model.matrix(Terms, mf)
  if (ncol(X) != (1 + attr(Terms, "intercept"))) 
    stop("Deming regression requires a single predictor variable")
  xx <- X[, ncol(X), drop = FALSE]
  if (!usepattern) 
    fit <- deming.fit1(xx, Y, wt, xstd, ystd, intercept = attr(Terms, "intercept"))
  else fit <- deming.fit2(xx, Y, wt, stdpat, intercept = attr(Terms, "intercept"))
  yhat <- fit$coefficients[1] + fit$coefficients[2] * xx
  fit$residuals <- Y - yhat

  if (x) 
    fit$x <- X
  if (y) 
    fit$y <- Y
  if (model) 
    fit$model <- mf
  na.action <- attr(mf, "na.action")
  if (length(na.action)) 
    fit$na.action <- na.action
  fit$n <- length(Y)
  fit$terms <- Terms
  fit$call <- Call
  fit
}

deming.aux(y ~ x + 0, df, xstd=sy, ystd=sy)
$`coefficients`
[1] 0.000000 4.324481

$se
[1] 0.2872988 0.7163073

$sigma
[1] 2.516912

$residuals
          [,1]
1   9.19499513
2   2.13037957
3   3.00064886
4   2.16751905
5   0.00168729
6   4.75834265
7   3.44108236
8   6.40028085
9   6.63531039
10 -1.48624851

$model
            y          x     (xstd)     (ystd)
1   2.1459817 -1.6300251 0.48826221 0.48826221
2   1.3163362 -0.1882407 0.46002166 0.46002166
3   1.5263967 -0.3409084 0.55771660 0.55771660
4  -0.9078000 -0.7111417 0.81145673 0.81145673
5  -1.6768719 -0.3881527 0.01563191 0.01563191
6  -0.6114545 -1.2417205 0.41675425 0.41675425
7  -0.7783790 -0.9757150 0.82498713 0.82498713
8   1.1240046 -1.2200946 0.84072712 0.84072712
9  -0.3091330 -1.6058442 0.35926078 0.35926078
10  0.7215432  0.5105333 0.23674788 0.23674788

$n
[1] 10

$terms
y ~ x + 0
...
```

To adapt the function I have performed, these steps:

1 .- Load the internal functions of the package.

```
deming.fit1 <- getAnywhere(deming.fit1)[[2]][[1]]
deming.fit2 <- getAnywhere(deming.fit2)[[2]][[1]]
```

2 .- Locate the problem and solve it, executing the function step by step with an example.

```
Y <- as.matrix(model.response(mf, type = "numeric"))
...
xx <- X[, ncol(X), drop = FALSE]
```

3 .- Fix other possible error generated by the changes.

In this case, delete the class of the output to avoid an error in the print.

**Bug report:**

Terry Therneau (the author of deming) uploaded a new version to CRAN, with this problem solved.

Comment: thanks for the new function. It seems to not fit anymore the intercept, whatever formula you input (even `y~x`), right?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. It should work correctly with intercept, I'll check to see what happens.

Comment: @JuanDiaz: You would help greatly if you could mark the lines you changed. Users who do not use this specific function could then learn how you solved the problem without installing the package.

Comment: Sorry for the delay I've been offline for a few days, I update the answer. The author of deming uploaded to new version to CRAN, it should appear on the servers soon.

Comment: thanks, great! nice to help improving the packages :-)